# Trying to understand how a document can be rendered correctly when GlyphMapping table is empty for Type0 MSGothic Pdf Font

Tags: pdf, fonts, adobe

I am working with a pdf document that does not seems to have any [Glyph mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVpaY.png) information in the document but the Adobe reader application render the document correctly. I am using Pdf Debugger to view the document properties. Hoping that someone will help me understand how the application is able to render the document.

It is my understanding that for Type 0 fonts, the mapping data has to be present in the pdf and the string to be shown is interpreted as pairs of bytes representing CIDs.

- The ToUnicode property does not have any mapping table.

Pdf content extracted using Pdf Debugger

```
(\201@\201\203\222\312\212\372\201\204) Tj
(2022) Tj
```

From ToUnicode property:

```
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
12 dict begin
begincmap
/CIDSystemInfo
<< /Registry (Adobe)
/Ordering (UCS) /Supplement 0 >> def
/CMapName /Adobe-Identity-UCS def
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<0000> <FFFF>
endcodespacerange
1 beginbfchar
<003B> <0058>
endbfchar
endcmap CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop end end
```

Answer (score 0):

For rendering the PDF, the **ToUnicode** map is not needed at all, it is only used for text extraction. Even for text extraction, though, there may or may not be other information in the PDF (e.g. certain **Encoding** values) that can be used instead.

---

In a comment you wonder

> In that case, how does an application know what '(\201@\201\203\222\312\212\372\201\204) Tj' maps to?

There are multiple options:

- The **Encoding** entry of the font may contain a mapping from the codes used in the content stream to names of the characters in the font.
- The **CIDSystemInfo** dictionary can contain a **Registry**/**Ordering**/**Supplement** tuple identifying the character collection.
- The **CIDToGIDMap** may specify a mapping from CIDs to glyph indices.
- Fonts have a built-in encoding.

Which of these options are considered in which order, depends on the kind of font. For details have a look at chapter 9 "Text" of the PDF specification ISO 32000, e.g. in the version shared by Adobe at https://www.adobe.com/go/pdfreference/

Comment: In that case, how does an application know what '(\201@\201\203\222\312\212\372\201\204) Tj' maps to?